# Enable checkbox work only once

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I need to enable/disable checkboxes each time when user choice edit/cancel.
I tested this on my Android phone and tablet.
On page load HTML code:

```
<div class="ui-checkbox ui-mini"><label class="m-r-2 ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-on">E-mail</label><input data-theme="b" data-mini="true" checked="" type="checkbox" name="mail" disabled="disabled"></div>
```

JS code(click on Edit):

```
$("#"+formid+" .oldform input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
```

JS code(click on Cancel - I replace all changes with the old html):

```
$("#"+formid+" .oldform").html("");
$("#"+formid+" .oldform").append(oldhtml2[prefix_arr]);
```

So...
First time when I click on Edit everyting is fine -> checkbox is enable.

```
<div class="ui-checkbox ui-mini"><label class="m-r-2 ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-on">E-mail</label><input data-theme="b" data-mini="true" checked="" type="checkbox" name="mail"></div>
```

First time when I click on Cancel evereyting is fine -> checkbox is disabled.

```
<div class="ui-checkbox ui-mini"><label class="m-r-2 ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-on">E-mail</label><input data-theme="b" data-mini="true" checked="" type="checkbox" name="mail" disabled="disabled"></div>
```

Secont time on edit -> Remove attribute disabled, but when I tap on checkbox, can't check or uncheck.

```
<div class="ui-checkbox ui-mini"><label class="m-r-2 ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-on">E-mail</label><input data-theme="b" data-mini="true" checked="" type="checkbox" name="mail"></div>
```

I can't see where is the problem.

**Edited:**

When I use **.trigger(create);** after append(), on the second Edit click, result is this:

```
<div class="ui-checkbox ui-mini"><div class="ui-checkbox ui-state-disabled ui-mini"><label class="m-r-2 ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-checkbox-on ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left" for="mail">E-mail</label><input type="checkbox" name="mail" data-mini="true" data-theme="b" id="mail" disabled=""></div></div>
```

Checkbox is dublicated, and I can't check or uncheck. Here is example [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/bawile/1/edit)

Comment: There is no problem if you don't use jQuery Mobile: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y123ws3a/). But you should understand that jQuery Mobile not only wraps standard element to beautify view, but also adds element event handlers. What is all about: you probably should use `.trigger("create")`, or `.trigger("refresh")`, or something like this after `.append()` to notify jQuery Mobile that it should handle added HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `prop()`

```
$('input').prop('disabled', false); // or true to disable
```